# Get sql type name from DbType

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to print real datbase type name from `DbParameter.DbType`, but when I do something like this `DbParameter.DbType.ToString()` I get for example `Int32` instead of `int`, is there a command or a property to do that or am I going to need to write switch statement?

Here is code if someone will need it: [DbType to real SQL type string](http://www.networkozone.com/snippets/c-sharp/9/dbtype-to-real-sql-type-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own converter

The data type mappings can be found here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx)

Comment: just to speed up things for you an example can be found here http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid81BF77665BE889E51EB9B3861C9BFBDE4A1A7AC5.aspx